# Define a macro whose name is concatenated with "##" opeartor

Tags: c, macros

I would like to define a macro. Its name should be concatenated from another macro. The code is like below:

```
#ifndef PORT_NUMBER // This macro could be defined in compile time
#define PORT_NUMBER 3
#endif

#define UART_PIN_TX_PORT(x) UART_PIN_TX_PORT_(x)
#define UART_PIN_TX_PORT_(x) UART_PIN_TX_PORT ## x

#ifndef UART_PIN_TX_PORT(PORT_NUMBER)
#define UART_PIN_TX_PORT(PORT_NUMBER) -1 // This line is question. It's wrong but how to do it properly?
#endif
```

The second last line is a wrong usage of such function. How should I define such a macro properly?

Comment: This cannot be done. `#define` works on the single identifier directly after it.

Comment: I think OP wants that line to expand to `#define UART_PIN_TX_PORT3 -1`. It's not a dupe, simply not doable.

Comment: @John Bollinger, I don't see how https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630548/c-expand-macro-with-token-pasting is relevant.

Comment: @ikegami, because this question's `UART_PIN_TX_PORT(PORT_NUMBER)` expands to `UART_PIN_TX_PORTPORT_NUMBER`, whereas it appears that they want it to expand to `UART_PIN_TX_PORT3`.

Comment: @John Bollinger, They're trying to check if a *macro* named UART_PIN_TX_PORT3  exists. And they're trying to create a *macro* named UART_PIN_TX_PORT3 if it doesn't exist. The linked Q&A is about generating C symbol names, not macro names.

Comment: It makes sense (but not doable) if you consider it as `#ifndef UART_PIN_TX_PORT3 #define UART_PIN_TX_PORT3 -1 #endif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use token pasting to construct the name of a macro to define.  `#define` directives require a single preprocessing token of type *identifier* for use as the macro name.  Token pasting is not relevant until macro expansion is being performed, which is strictly after macro definitions have been set.

I suppose that you're trying to save space, but note that this ...

> ```
> #ifndef PORT_NUMBER // This macro could be defined in compile time
> #define PORT_NUMBER 3
> #endif
>
> #define UART_PIN_TX_PORT(x) UART_PIN_TX_PORT_(x)
> #define UART_PIN_TX_PORT_(x) UART_PIN_TX_PORT ## x
>
> #ifndef UART_PIN_TX_PORT(PORT_NUMBER)
> #define UART_PIN_TX_PORT(PORT_NUMBER) -1 // This line is question. It's wrong but how to do it properly?
> #endif
> ```

... is already almost as big as ...

```
#ifndef UART_PIN_TX_PORT1
#define UART_PIN_TX_PORT1 -1
#endif

#ifndef UART_PIN_TX_PORT2
#define UART_PIN_TX_PORT2 -1
#endif

#ifndef UART_PIN_TX_PORT3
#define UART_PIN_TX_PORT3 -1
#endif
```

, but the latter is much clearer (not to mention correct).

If you want a tiny bit of abstraction, then you can also add something like

```
#ifndef UART_PIN_TX_PORT
#define UART_PIN_TX_PORT UART_PIN_TX_PORT3
#endif
```

to the latter.

Comment: My intention is to get the dynamic macro definition and have thought many other solutions like having both defined macro to indicate the existence and an integer to contain the actual value predefined as a macro function. But I think I have to go with this way as it is much clearer and it should be fine for my application as there will be no more than 10 UART ports.

Comment: Re “My intention is to get the dynamic macro definition”: You do not have to do it with the C preprocessor. There are plenty of scripting/editing languages that can generate the text you need. Do not think “I have X tool, how do I use it to solve Y problem?” Think “I have Y problem, what is a good way to solve it?”

Comment: `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, and `#if defined` also all three take a single identifier argument which is not macro expanded, so the `#ifndef UART_PIN_TX_PORT(PORT_NUMBER)` line in the original code also won't work as intended.