Refactoring test sources
I have five test source files with these contents:
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "acutest.h"

#include "../src/FileBuf.h"
#include "../src/readlines_fread.c"

void test_readlines_fread_success(void)
{
    /* The lines and line lengths are at most 1024 in sample1.txt. */
    char buf[1024];
    char *lines[1024];
    size_t line_count = 0;
    FILE *const fp = fopen("test/sample.txt", "r");

    TEST_ASSERT(fp);

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
        TEST_ASSERT((lines[line_count] = strdup(buf)));
        ++line_count;
    }
    
    rewind(fp);

    FileBuf fbuf = {};

    TEST_CHECK(readlines_fread(fp, &fbuf));
    TEST_CHECK(fbuf.count == 555);
    TEST_CHECK(fbuf.size == 120635);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fbuf.count; ++i) {
        TEST_CHECK((strcmp(lines[i], fbuf.lines[i].line) == 0));
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_readlines_fread_success", test_readlines_fread_success },
    { nullptr, nullptr },
};

The only difference between them is the last include directive is different, the function name is different, the function being called in the first TEST_CHECK() is different, and the first entry in the TEST_LIST array is different.
Well, it is just one name in 5 different places, fread here.
The other 4 test files are the same, except that fread is replaced with getline, mmap_getline, mmap_memchr, and read respectively.
I am looking to reduce these 5 test sources to a single one. I am aware that I can directly pass the header with the -include flag to GCC and Clang, but how I similarly replace the function names (fread, getline, mmap_getline, mmap_memchr, and read) with some macro-trickery?
Say, when building for the first time, all instances of fread should remain the same. Then when building for the second time, all instance of fread should be replaced with getline, and then mmap_getline(), and so on.

Wouldn't it make more sense to replace all of these with macros in the include file itself, and then only change that?

@tripleee The include directive is including the .c being tested directly. I can't change the code being tested. If you meant something else, kindly clarify.

Then maybe put those definitions in a separate include file.

Please don't include source files. Build them into object files, and then link all source files into the executable program file.

Use #ifdef and -D... compilation define, as in gcc -DWITH_FREAD -std=c2x -pedantic -W -Wall ...

I understand what you're doing (what you want) with the macros and the #include as I've done similar a number of times. But, I think you don't need to use macros. Use a function pointer instead. One copy of the test function: void test_readlines_fread_success(int (*fnc)(FILE *,FileBuf *)) Then, replace TEST_CHECK(readlines_fread(fp, &fbuf)); with TEST_CHECK(fnc(fp, &fbuf));

For some examples, see my answers: how to do right shift rounding middle towards even How to create recursion for vector addition? What is the effect of float (*vals)[n] = malloc(sizeof(float[n]))?

@CraigEstey Okay, that's a fine and the third alternative. But the TEST_LIST is already such an array that the testing code in acutest.h would be looping over. I'd use this solution when I am not using an external library. Thanks.

If you have a macro that expands to look like a header name, you can use:
#include INCLUDE_FILE_NAME

So, you could compile with -DINCLUDE_FILE_NAME='"../src/readlines_fread.c"'.
The line:
{ "test_readlines_fread_success", test_readlines_fread_success },

could be converted to use a macro:
{ FUNCTION_NAME_AND_POINTER(test_readlines_fread_success) },

with:
#define FUNCTION_NAME_AND_POINTER(name) #name, name

It isn't clear how the TEST_LIST array declaration is used — it seems to combine a type with some sort of array name.  Frankly, it is more obfuscatory than beneficial.  It would be better split into:
TEST_ARRAY_TYPE Test_Array_Name[] =
{
    …
};

However, in many ways, that particular observation is tangential, but my test code will use that revised notation.
It isn't very clear in the question which names are "the function name".  There seem to be a lot of places with various things that could be "the function name" embedded in them.  If the FUT (function under test) is readlines_fread, then the build environment can do a fair amount of the work for you.
Here is a version of your file with some macros which would presumably be placed into a header, probably acutest.h for production use.  My source is in test97.c.
/* SO 7856-3912 */

//#include <assert.h>
//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include "acutest.h"
//#include "FileBuf.h"

/* Check configuration */
#ifndef INCLUDE_FILE_NAME
#error You must define INCLUDE_FILE_NAME as the name of the source file to test
#endif /* INCLUDE_FILE_NAME */
#ifndef FUNCTION_UNDER_TEST
#error You must define FUNCTION_UNDER_TEST as the name of the function under test
#endif /* FUNCTION_UNDER_TEST */

#include INCLUDE_FILE_NAME

#define TEST_FUNCTION_NAME(name)    test_ ## name ## _success
#define TEST_FUNCTION(name)         TEST_FUNCTION_NAME(name)

#define TEST_ARRAY_ENTRY(name)      #name, name
#define TEST_ARRAY_EXPANSION(name)  TEST_ARRAY_ENTRY(name)
#define TEST_ARRAY_MAPPING(name)    TEST_ARRAY_EXPANSION(TEST_FUNCTION(name))


void TEST_FUNCTION(FUNCTION_UNDER_TEST)(void)
{
    /* The lines and line lengths are at most 1024 in sample1.txt. */
    char buf[1024];
    char *lines[1024];
    size_t line_count = 0;
    FILE *const fp = fopen("test/sample.txt", "r");

    TEST_ASSERT(fp);

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
        TEST_ASSERT((lines[line_count] = strdup(buf)));
        ++line_count;
    }
    
    rewind(fp);

    FileBuf fbuf = {};

    TEST_CHECK(FUNCTION_UNDER_TEST(fp, &fbuf));
    TEST_CHECK(fbuf.count == 555);
    TEST_CHECK(fbuf.size == 120635);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fbuf.count; ++i) {
        TEST_CHECK((strcmp(lines[i], fbuf.lines[i].line) == 0));
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

TEST_ARRAY_TYPE Test_Array_Name[] = {
    { TEST_ARRAY_MAPPING(FUNCTION_UNDER_TEST) },
    { nullptr, nullptr },
};

I've commented out the headers, and tested with a file readlines_fread.c in the current directory that contains just:
Contents of readlines_fread.c

The makefile looks like this:
FUNCTION_UNDER_TEST = readlines_fread
INCLUDE_FILE_NAME = "$(FUNCTION_UNDER_TEST).c"

CFLAGS = -E -DINCLUDE_FILE_NAME='$(INCLUDE_FILE_NAME)' -DFUNCTION_UNDER_TEST=$(FUNCTION_UNDER_TEST)

PROG = test97

all: $(PROG).o

The preprocessed output looks like this:
# 1 "test97.c"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 418 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "test97.c" 2
# 17 "test97.c"
# 1 "./readlines_fread.c" 1
Content of file readlines_fread.c
# 18 "test97.c" 2
# 27 "test97.c"
void test_readlines_fread_success(void)
{

    char buf[1024];
    char *lines[1024];
    size_t line_count = 0;
    FILE *const fp = fopen("test/sample.txt", "r");

    TEST_ASSERT(fp);

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp)) {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
        TEST_ASSERT((lines[line_count] = strdup(buf)));
        ++line_count;
    }

    rewind(fp);

    FileBuf fbuf = {};

    TEST_CHECK(readlines_fread(fp, &fbuf));
    TEST_CHECK(fbuf.count == 555);
    TEST_CHECK(fbuf.size == 120635);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < fbuf.count; ++i) {
        TEST_CHECK((strcmp(lines[i], fbuf.lines[i].line) == 0));
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

TEST_ARRAY_TYPE Test_Array_Name[] = {
    { "test_readlines_fread_success", test_readlines_fread_success },
    { nullptr, nullptr },
};

I believe that is very close to what you wanted to achieve.  By running make FUNCTION_UNDER_TEST=readlines_getline, you can switch to a different source file and function name.
Obviously, you can identify where files are to be included from with an option like -I../src provided as one of the CFLAGS.
GNU Make copies the output into test97.o because it adds -c and -o test97.o to the compiler command line:
cc -E -DINCLUDE_FILE_NAME='"readlines_fread.c"' -DFUNCTION_UNDER_TEST=readlines_fread   -c -o test97.o test97.c

Other variants of make may have different rules.
gcc -E -DINCLUDE_FILE_NAME='"readlines_fread.c"' -DFUNCTION_UNDER_TEST=readlines_fread -c test97.c

See also What are the benefits of a relative path such as "../include/header.h" for a header?

It is hard to generate header names enclosed in double quotes because they look like strings, and that presents problems because strings have their own set of semantics.
The #include notation shown in wizzwizz4's answer (revision 1) is not going to work. String concatenation occurs in Phase 6 (see C11 §5.1.1.2 Translation phases) while preprocessing occurs in Phase 4. You can use a macro name in #include MACRO_NAME, but MACRO_NAME must expand to "file.name" or <file.name> pretty much directly. See also §6.10.2 Source file inclusion ¶4 and especially footnote 170.
However, you could use the angle-bracket notation to good effect.
For example:
#define HEADER_NAME(base) <base.h>

#include HEADER_NAME(somename)

With the correct -I options (-I. for the case where somename.h is in the current directory), this will include somename.h for you.
Clearly, you could adapt this to include a source file in another directory, but you may still have to include appropriate -I options on the command line:
#define SOURCE_FILE(base) <../src/base.c>

#include SOURCE_FILE(testfile)

Or (with RELATIVE_PATH more plausibly set on the command line):
#define RELATIVE_PATH ../src
#define HEADER_NAME(base) <RELATIVE_PATH/base.h>

#include HEADER_NAME(somename)

This works with GCC (aka Clang) on macOS, at any rate.

What you need to use also depends on where you do the compilation.  Note that the POSIX specification for the c99
compiler includes a specification of how #include <name.h> and #include "name.h" interact with -Isome/path/name:

-I  directory
Change the algorithm for searching for headers whose names are not absolute pathnames to look in the directory named by the directory pathname before looking in the usual places. Thus, headers whose names are enclosed in double-quotes ("") shall be searched for first in the directory of the file with the #include line, then in directories named in -I options, and last in the usual places. For headers whose names are enclosed in angle brackets ("<>"), the header shall be searched for only in directories named in -I options and then in the usual places. Directories named in -I options shall be searched in the order specified. If the -I option is used to specify a directory that is one of the usual places searched by default, the results are unspecified. Implementations shall support at least ten instances of this option in a single c99 command invocation.

Note, in particular, the rule fragment:

… shall be searched for first in the directory of the file with the #include line …

In a comment, you ask:

And if the files are included with "cread/src/FileBuf.h", what'd I need?

Then, in the cread/test directory, you'd need -I../...  Or if the project is in /home/username/project/cread (with sub-directories test and src), you could use -I$HOME/project (in shell notation; -I$(HOME)/project or -I${HOME}/project in make notation – and the notation -I${HOME}/project would work in the makefile too).
Basically, the preprocessor is going to take the name in the #include directive (e.g. cread/src/fileBuf.h and prepend items from the list of -I options to create a file name.
So, with -I../.., you'd end up with ../../cread/src/fileBuf.h, which should be the pathname of the file relative to the test sub-directory.  Or with -I${HOME}/project, you'd have /home/username/project/cread/src/fileBuf.h.

"Re: It isn't clear how the TEST_LIST array declaration is used — it seems to combine a type with some sort of array name." ==> It is for acutest.h (a header only testing library), TEST_LIST is what it expects and loops over. 2) I like your alternative solution to my problem.

Since you didn't include the content of acutest.h in the question (and there's no real reason to do so), it remains unclear what TEST_LIST is.  However, as I also noted, it doesn't matter all that much — it works adequately for you in the context.

I read the linked question, and I am already sold (I was despising the ".." ), but I am at a loss at how to use the suggested includes. The project name is cread. cread consists of src and test. test has these relative includes. I tried ./cread/src/FileBuf.h, and cread/src/FileBuf.h, and ./src/FileBuf.h, and src/FileBuf.h, but neither of them were found when I ran make. Is there an SO question that explains this? I have not played around with includes much before. I believe it is 'cause when you include with "", the relative path is from the current file location.

I've added some extra notes to my answer.  You might need to add -I../src on the compiler command line to find the files in the src directory from code in the test directory.  If there are #include directives with source file names such as src/header.h or test/header.h, then you would need -I.. on the command line (either instead of or as well as -I../src).  If the files are included with "../src/header.h", then you need to specify a directory with -I such that the files can be found — so -I../test or -I../src would do the job. It becomes of a game of "how many ways?"

And if the files are included with "cread/src/FileBuf.h", what'd I need? (I am still experimenting. :)) Okay -I.. works.


Say, when building for the first time, all instances of fread should remain the same. Then when building for the second time, all instance of fread should be replaced with getline, and then mmap_getline(), and so on.

Not sure what the conventional file extension for this hack is.
testbit.chchc
/* don't know if this works: might need another layer of macro */
#include "../src/" #TESTME ".c"

void test_ ## TESTME ## _success(void) {
    FILE *const fp = fopen("test/sample.txt", "r");
    FileBuf fbuf = {};

    TEST_CHECK(TESTME(fp, &fbuf));

    fclose(fp);
}

TEST_LIST = {
    { "test_" #TESTME  "_success", test_ ## TESTME ## _success },
    { nullptr, nullptr },
};

testall.c
#define TESTME readlines_fread
#include "testbit.chchc"
#define TESTME readlines_getline
#include "testbit.chchc"
/// ...

This code is fairly meaningless as written (defining TEST_LIST so many times is definitely some kind of error), but the general approach is sound.

Yes, we require a STRINGIFY() for the #s.

Okay, ## TESTME ## is not going to compile. ## can only be used in macro definitions. A CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT_INDIRECT(a, b) macro with one level of indirection (through a second CONCAT_INDIRECT(a, b) a ## b) would do. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12630576/20017547

The #include notation is not going to work.  String concatenation occurs in Phase 6 (see C11 §5.1.1.2 Translation phases) while preprocessing occurs in Phase 4.  You can use a macro name in #include MACRO_NAME, but MACRO_NAME must expand to "file.name" or <file.name> pretty much directly.   See also §6.10.2 Source file inclusion ¶4  and especially footnote 170.

@JonathanLeffler So in Phase 4, #include "../src/" #TESTME ".c" would become #include "../src/" "TESTME" ".c", which would be invalid because string concatenation occurs in Phase 6, and would also not work because the # (and ## for that matter) operator does not expand its operand, is that correct?

@Harith — The stringize (#) and concatenate (##) operators are only applicable inside the RHS (right-hand side) expansion of a macro.  Otherwise, they're just the characters # and ##.  Strike 1 — #include "../src/" #TESTME ".c" is not the RHS of a macro.  Strike 2 — even if that were fixed, the result would be #include "../src/" "readlines_fread" ".c", which is not a valid #include directive — see footnote 170 in the C11 standard.
